# How to set property value in instance time?

Tags: php, oop

In C# is usual set object property in instance time

Like this code

```
People p = new People(){Name = "John", Age = 18};
```

Have any solution like this in PHP?

Comment: You can pass them into the constructor, but it's much better to have getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, other than the [normal constructor methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), no, you can't do that in PHP. However, there are RFC's [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/automatic_property_initialization) and [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor-promotion) for something similar to this, so maybe in a few version's time it will be available.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
class People() {
 public $name = "";
 public $age = "";
 public function __construct($name,$age) {
   $this->name = $name;
   $this->age = $age;
 }
}

$obj = new People("John", 18);
```

For more information you can visit: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: This is working, but I do not want put it in the parameters, because it can turn list of parameters so long, and need set values in sequence

Comment: Than you can use getter and setter of php. documentation is here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the construction of the class, but you *can* do it.

```
<?php
class Person {
    public function __construct(array $params = array()) {
        foreach ($params as $property => $value) {
            $this->{$property} = $value;
        }
    }
}

$p = new Person(array('Name' => 'Bob', 'Age' => 18));
echo $p->Age; //18
```